# Is it possible to get all elements in a Matrix field by type or field name

Tags: matrix

I found a way to do something like this

```
 {% set allBlocks =  craft.entries.matrixes %}
```

Which seems to return all the matrix blocks.. or at least I think it is?

But if try to filter down like:

```
  {% set allBlocks =  craft.entries.matrixes.type('document') %}
```

I get nothing.

Any ideas how to get all the Matrix blocks by type or better still all the Matrix blocks in a particular field?

Would i need to setup a plugin for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `craft.entries.matrixes` variable available natively in Craft.

(`craft.entries` returns an *ElementCriteriaModel*, which does not have a `matrixes` property explicitly set.)

So, `craft.entries.matrixes` is actually looking for `ElementCriteriaModel->matrixes()`, which could *implicitly* exist if:

- You have a field called *matrixes*, *or*
- There's a plugin in the mix that is changing functionality

You'll need a plugin to run these custom queries. Luckily Craft's *MatrixService* has plenty of methods that would be helpful.

Also, Low created a plugin ([LowBlocks](https://github.com/low/lowblocks)) to do this sort of thing, which might fit your need, or at least offer a helpful starting point.

Comment: Low's plugin was exactly what i needed and still works great.  Thanks Michael!